# Java RESTful Web Service - Annotate an Interface instead of a Class

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, interface, jersey

I am trying to setup a simple web service (deploy on tomcat) which goes like this:

```
@Path("/api")
public interface Api {

    @GET
    @Path("categ")
    public String getCateg();
}
```

and I have the following class implementing the interface:

```
public class RAPI implements API {
    public String getCateg() { ... }
}
```

My web.xml looks as follows:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.api.resources</param-value> <!-- THIS IS CORRECT -->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I try to deploy on Tomcat I get the following (rather expected error):

```
 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
 INFO: No provider classes found.
```

Which (not copied the whole trace here) tells me that although it found the API interface it cannot instantiate it.

How can I declare which of the implementing classes will actually act as the REST web service?

Comment: I'm not sure you can annotate an interface with the JAX-RS annotations. It would confuse the container if you had multiple implementations. Why do you want to annotate the interface?

Comment: no particular reason. i am just experimenting. I really don't know whether it's a good idea.

Comment: A good reason to annotate the interface is share the interfaces between the rest-server and the rest-client. That makes developing a client almost trivial (remote proxy) in many jax-rs implementations. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having an interface annotated with JAX-RS allows you to create remote proxy clients. We do this with Apache CXF, but I haven't tried it with Jersey.

EG in my Spring config I can have;

```
<jaxrs:client id="myClient" inheritHeaders="true"
            address="http://myhost/rs"
            serviceClass="com.mycorp.restful.MyServiceInterface">
  <jaxrs:headers>
    <entry key="Accept" value="application/xml"/>
  </jaxrs:headers>
</jaxrs:client>
```

I can now use this spring bean by just calling the methods. I don't have to create a Client and I don't have to care about the relative paths of the different RS services it defines.

Answer (score 0):

As for using Interface for REST Service it is a good idea IMHO. But one thing do not annotate Interface itself leave it for implementation. This way you may have more flexibility. For instance,

```
public Interface Readable {

    @GET
    @Path("/read/{id}")
    public String read(@PathParam("id") Integer id);
}

@Service
@Path("/book")
public class Book implements Readable, ... {
    ...
    public String read(Integer id){...}
}
```

As for Jersey proxy check this:
https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.0/jersey/project/jersey-proxy-client/dependencies.html